Resubmitting a grant application for a postdoc research: how to approach changes when you think one reviewer made some mistakes
I recently submitted an application for a interdisciplinary postdoc research with a grant specifically dedicated to skills development.
In a scale including "outstanding, excellent, very good, good, average, poor", I received two reviews: one mentioning that the project is outstanding. The other one mentioning that the project is average.
Now, the second review has some elements that I would argue are over-criticizing the application without valid arguments. In particular, the reviewer suggested that I do not have the minimum basic knowledge to profit from this research. To make the type of comment clearer to many, consider the following case.
I am writing a proposal for an interdisciplinary project that aims to make scientific research combining 3 fields. One of these is sociology. The comment received by the reviewer was similar to this:
"The applicant mentions that their professional experience as a sociologist to illustrate their expertise in scientific research. I really do not think that sociology and scientific research are the same thing".
The reviewer did not read my CV, nor the outputs from my previous research, nor considered the expertise of the mentors or how their expertise complemented mine in such a project.
Now, I find these types of comments neither useful nor scientifically valid. I am asked to resubmit and I can exclude the mentioned reviewer in the next round. My strategy is to improve the text after the helpful comments of the first reviewer (the one judging my application outstanding). However, they request that I respond to the critiques of the reviewers and show how their comments helped me improve my application.
But I really believe that most of the comments given by the second reviewer were not helpful, and I am afraid that criticizing the received feedback may look bad during re-submission. How would you act in this case?

While I sympathize with you over being upset over this comment, I wouldn't say "The applicant is fundamentally unsuited to the project" is a trivial reason.

@AzorAhai-him-, I understand what you mean. Indeed I would agree that such a comment is an important reaon. The problem is that it is not argued and based solely on the personal preference of the reviewer rather than being a scientific reason. You can say: "the specific knowledge of the candidate in that specific field is not enough", which would suggest me to find an additional mentor to cover that subject. However, saying that something is not something else, when that argumentation is not supported, and just generalize it, is quite unprofessional in my opinion. In that sense I mean "trivial

Nevertheless, I think the title could be made more accurate to the reviewer's concerns for people browsing.

I edited the question title to make it more general and useful to future readers. I am not sure the title now fully represents my question, but maybe may better represent the answers from other users.

Can you clarify if your biosketch meets the actual merit review criteria?  I had a PI once say the reviews said "you don't have an expert in X on your project" -- she was the expert.  None of her listed publications mentioned that topic so... naturally they didn't really believe she was an expert.  We redid her biosketch and she got funded within a year.  You have to really look at the merit review criteria to see why you score poorly.  Shockingly, many people skip this step.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin, thank you for your contribution. Well, I do not sure I can. The reason is that the comments is not a comparison between two fields, but between a disciplinary field (e.g. sociology) and an umbrella term (e.g. science), and the mentioned disciplinary field is part of the fields usually included in the umbrella term (depending on how the research is done, and the specific context: problem is that the comment is not contextualized). My problem now is that I don't know how to address this: should I highlight it in the revision report? It sounds bad.

@TakeMeToTheMoon I would let this sit for a little while and come back to it when you have a clearer head. You do not need to argue with the reviewer about the relationship between sociology and science. You do need to make the case, if you are proposing a scientific study, that you have sufficient scientific background to conduct that research. If you do scientific research of a specific type relevant to your proposal, then your grant needs to say that. Saying "I've been a sociologist for X years" is not sufficient.

Arguably, if you plan to combine three fields, you need to show that you have expertise in all three, or at least that your collaborators/advisors do and will be sufficiently involved in the project for that expertise to matter. If, for example, the grant is only to pay for your own time and those other collaborators/advisors don't have any funding support, that could be a negative for the project. Even if it's a great idea, it may not have a good scope for a postdoctoral grant. I don't know, I haven't read your grant, just some superficial impressions of where criticism may come from.

@BryanKrause, Thank you for trying to help me. I really appreciate it. I just add a note to avoid being misinterpreted. I understand that there is not other option than trying to improve the text. However, I would know how to respond to misleading or harsh comments in case of a review for an article: I would say "I made these changes and not those because I believe that...". The thing is that I do not know how to do that in a submission for a grant, as I feel in a position where I have to please the reviewer(s) rather than arguing eventual mistakes, and the internet does not clarify this well.

@TakeMeToTheMoon I think it's quite similar for a paper and a grant: in both cases you're best off using the reviewers comments to make your submission better and worry less about debating/winning. If you wish to stand your ground on a point, that's fine, but the best way to do so is to use the reviewer's comments as an indication that you need to clarify or better support your position in the document itself, not just in response to the reviewer. It's not about convincing the reviewer, it's about the next reader not getting the same misconception.

You can still complain about the jerk reviewer among your friends, over a pint or whatever is an appropriate setting for you to relax and converse. If you're among other academics they'll have lots of similar stories to commiserate about.

Thank you @BryanKrause, right now it is coming to me the idea that instead of responding to the comments directly, I can eventually rephrase them like: "Reviewer 1 highlighted that [and here I put a more soft and addressable interpretation of the critique that hopefully may give a new light to the concept making it easier for me to address it in the text]". I guess that the response should not necessarily respond point by point, but I can summarize some main concerns that I see emerging from the whole feedback received.

@TakeMeToTheMoon The last time I got a bad review, it took me 4-5 weeks to reopen the comments, but I think it did make my paper better. And yes, that's the approach I would take. "Reviewer 2 expressed concerns about the applicability of my training to the proposed projects. I added paras 2 and 3 ... "

Welcome to academic peer review. This sort of thing is normal.
Extract any potentially helpful information from the reviews that you can for your resubmission. If someone says "you don't have the right experience", the constructive way for you to reframe that is "I need to make a more clear case that I have the right experience."

The reviewer did not read my CV, nor the outputs from my previous research, nor considered the expertise of the mentors or how their expertise complemented mine in such a project.

You likely need to weave these things directly into your grant to communicate them to reviewers. A reviewer is not going to dig through all the material in the grant to make a case for why your grant is excellent, you need to do it for them. Reviewers are often given limited time, may not be compensated or are compensated in a laughably minor way for their time, and are juggling the responsibility of reviewing your grant among many other responsibilities. Make it as easy as possible on them. They are not going to read all your previous research, they may not know your mentors or at least do not know them well.
When you explain how this reviewer's comments helped you improve your application, you can describe how the comments helped you to clarify how your specific expertise and the expertise of your mentors connect with the objectives of the grant.
It won't help improve your grant to think of the reviewer as wrong, I would rather think of them as unconvinced. Remember, they are your audience. Your job is to convey information to them and convince them. If something in your grant is unclear to one of your audience members, it's likely unclear to others, too. If they get something fundamentally wrong about your approach, then it may be that your audience needs a better explanation of why that approach is actually the best one and that it is you that are wrong to assume your audience already knows.

I recently submitted an application for a interdisciplinary postdoc research with a grant specifically dedicated to skills development.

I see you edited your original post from "build new knowledge" to "skills development". Every grant is specifically dedicated to build new knowledge. This isn't special. Are you sure this funding opportunity is directed towards skills development? From the reviewers' comments, I get the impression that they are expecting you to already have certain skills and that you are prepared to turn those skills into a productive endeavor. Make sure you understand what makes your grant proposal special and suited to this funding opportunity, and make sure a reader would understand it, too.
Remember also that grants are not funded merely for being adequate, they are judged in comparison to all the other excellent grant submissions being considered at the same time.

Thank you. I edited the question, as with "new knowledge" I meant "skills development". Can I ask you to expand your response? Here the fact is not about responding to harsh critiques. The problem here is it answering to critiques that are not helpful. As an example, let's say that I have a literature review saying: "1) What is there, 2) what is not there". The first reviewer says "the literature review says is great and 2 is a perceived problem". The second reviewer says: "The candidate says that 1 is already there, so I do not see the novelty". It's like my application was not actually read.

@TakeMeToTheMoon I do not see "new knowledge" and "skills development" as being particularly related; I'd be careful that you are using the right words, especially in your grant (not referring to these particular words, of course, but much more generally). If you are writing a grant to develop your own skills, I would first be very certain that the grant you are applying for supports that sort of development.

@TakeMeToTheMoon I would point you to the sentence in my answer "Extract any potentially helpful information from the reviews that you can...".  If you write about (1) and (2) and the second reviewer either didn't find (2) or didn't find it compelling, you should improve your case for (2), perhaps change the order of things to make sure (2) is out front, etc. It's your job to make the case for novelty, not the reviewer's job to convince themselves. It's your job to make your writing so clear that it cannot be misread.

Thank you Bryan. With due respect, I don't think this is the case. You seem to assume that reviews are always not-wrong. Sometimes, instead, reviewers may make mistakes, or being not adequate, and even suggest wrong things due to misinterpretation. My question is about how to deal with the re-submission (cover letter explaining changes) if I think that one reviewer misinterpreted my application. Sometimes it may happen. If one reviewer makes a clear correct summary of the objectives of the research, and the other does not, there is 50% of possibility that the problem is not with clarity.

@TakeMeToTheMoon I am not assuming that reviews are always not-wrong. I am telling you that as the writer, your best approach in resubmission is to take what you can from the reviews to improve your work, even if you think they are wrong. If you think you made your case but the reviewer misinterpreted, the productive thing you can do is to make it less likely the next reader will have the same misinterpretation. You are responsible for making your side of the communication as robust as possible.

If 50% of readers get it wrong, that absolutely does not mean "50% possibility the problem is not with clarity". Clarity is not a binary, where either everyone will understand or everyone will misunderstand. If half of your readers misunderstand, that strongly suggests a clarity problem. A sample size of 2 is not really enough to understand the scope of the problem in either direction, of course, but it's all the data you have.

To illustrate, @TakeMeToTheMoon, consider the example comment you give in the question.  I wouldn't see professional experience working as a sociologist as evidence of skill in scientific research either.  If that's not a claim you were trying to make then you should determine why the reviewer might have read your application that way, and fix it.  Or if you intentionally do make that claim, then you should think about why some members of your highly-educated audience find it unconvincing, and either adjust the language or develop the claim more fully.

A relevant quote I like: "When people tell you something's wrong or doesn't work for them, they are almost always right. When they tell you exactly what they think is wrong and how to fix it, they are almost always wrong.". -Neil Gaiman
